# How do I undo ggplot data error code to plot data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, neural-network, aes, mlp

I keep getting the same error when I enter this code:

```
ggplot(exchangeGBP) + aes(Date, GBP/EUR) + geom_line(color = "deepskyblue")
```

the error code: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Date' not found`

should I install a package or change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` before `aes` seems to be the issue

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(exchangeGBP, aes(Date, `GBP/EUR`)) + 
         geom_line(color = 'deepskyblue') +
         theme_bw()
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
exchangeGBP <- tibble(Date = seq(Sys.Date() - 10, 
      length.out = 10, by = '1 day'), `GBP/EUR` = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: It worked thank you.